# How to determine usercontrol selected child

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a user control, a dropdown list, that's comprised of many component controls. 
The main HtmlInputText will post back on an enter but on loss of focus it doesn't and I need that to update other controls. 
I added an onblur function, and it gets called, but I only want to postback when the element getting focus isn't part of the user control.

How do I determine what is selected and if it's a child of the control?

Markup:

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="MultiDropDown" Namespace="MultiDropDownLib" TagPrefix="MultiDropDownLib" %>
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <table style="width: 328px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ProductClass
                </td>
                <td>
                    <MultiDropDownLib:MultiDropDown ID="MultiDropDown1" runat="server" TextBoxClass="textboxDD"
                        PostOnBlur="true" />
                </td>
   ...
```

And in the control:

```
if (PostOnBlur)
{
    txtItemList.Attributes.Add("onblur", string.Format("PostBack();", this.ClientID));
}
```

In the PostBack I want to determine what has focus and if it's part of the control. The original control came from: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219977/MultiDropDown-A-multiple-selection-Dropdown-contro](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219977/MultiDropDown-A-multiple-selection-Dropdown-contro/%20%22MultiDropDown)

Comment: Can you post the markup of your asp.net page?  It's not certain how exactly the items are structured.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it with javascript and jQuery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":input").focus(function () {
            if (this.name.indexOf("$WebUserControl1") > -1) {
                alert("It is child of my control.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just replace `$WebUserControl1` with the name of your user control. This could also be Dynamic if you want to. Basically all of the children of the usercontrol will contain the name of their parent because WebUserControls inherit from TemplateControl which implements the INamingContainer interface.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Hanlet, I'm new in this world and haven't touched jQuery yet. I'm guessing that means including jQuery as part of the control and will have to read up on what happens if it's already part of the form, versions and all that.

Comment: No problem GBrookman, you actually need to include the jQuery in the page and not in the control. The only thing you need to make sure is that the control that is getting focus contains part of it's parent in the name.

Comment: I have that working but...what I really want is to fire the post when the user leaves the control. I tried using :visible but if I click outside the control but not on another element it doesn't work. Should I use onmouseout or is there a different loss of focus option.

Comment: Use the OnBlur() event for the TextBox if you want to do it with Javascript. You can always bind the OnBlurry() event with a Javascript function that will call the __DoPostBack() method if you want to do a server trip.